# What package manager that upgrade incrementally beside snap?

Tags: package-management, snap

Is there any packages manager that upgrade package incrementally like snap but without the container concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cupt (*cupt*) provides a console interface to Cupt library, which implements high-level package manager for Debian and derivatives. Cupt is written with flexibility and reliability in mind and uses dpkg as the back-end.

Cupt uses the same APT infrastructure, e.g. index files, deb cache archive files, configuration files. It understands some of widely used APT options.

cupt can be installed by `sudo apt install cupt` in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Some features:

- strict full-case resolver
- resolver reasons tracking
- command-line and 'cupt::*' option name checker
- case-sensitive search
- pinning by source package name;
- pinning by package groups using shell-like patterns;
- configurable 'depends' and 'rdepends' subcommands
- 'satisfy' subcommand
- support of LZMA-compressed indexes
- source versions synchronization
- 'shell' subcommand (to get command history, search etc. working, install the package 'libreadline7')
- integration with debdelta (to get it, install the package 'debdelta' with `sudo apt install debdelta`)
- system snapshots (needs packages 'dpkg-dev' and 'dpkg-repack')

Its interface is mostly like apt-get/aptitude console interface.

---

#### debdelta

debdelta (*debdelta*) is a program suite designed to compute changes between Debian packages. These changes (deltas) are similar to the output of the "diff" program in that they may be used to store and transmit only the changes between Debian packages.

This suite contains 'debdelta-upgrade', that downloads deltas and use them
to create all Debian packages needed for an 'apt-get upgrade'. It may be used in a Debian/unstable host (to speed up download of new packages), or in a Debian/stable host (for security updates).

Similarly, when this package is installed, the 'cupt' package manager will use deltas to upgrade the host.

debdelta can be installed by `sudo apt install debdelta` in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.